# How to put an array in a constructor in JS?

Tags: javascript

For instace - I need to create a class that can be used to create multiple farms. Each farm must contain an id, a location and an array of animals. Each animal must have a name and quantity (so basically an animal will be an object).
I don't know how to put this array of animals inside the class.

```
class Farms {
  constructor (id, location, animals) {
  this.id = id;
  this.location = location;
  this.animals = animals;
```

} - how can I make 'animals' into an array?

Comment: You have to create a class Animal too!

Comment: Not necessarily @XMehdi01. Depends on the scope of the exercise.

Comment: Example: `[ { name: 'cow', qty: 3 }, { name: 'bear', qty: 13 } ]`: see [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects). Edit: yes you can have bears on a farm.

Answer (score 4):

Create `Animal` class, instantiate some animals from that class, and pass it to `Farm` object:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, quantity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
}
class Farm {
  constructor(id, location, animals) {
    this.id = id;
    this.location = location;
    this.animals = animals;
  }
}
const animals = [
  new Animal("Bird", 2),
  new Animal("Rabbit", 3),
  new Animal("Dogs", 1)
];
const farm = new Farm(1, "MyFarm", animals);
console.log(farm);
```

*Note: It's generally a good practice to use singular nouns instead of plural nouns for naming classes.

e.g. name your class `Farm` instead of `Farms`.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go OOP way then it's better to create an Animal class as well and pass an array of that.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, qty) {
    this.name = name
    this.qty = qty
  }
}

const animal1 = new Animal('A name', 1)
const animal2 = new Animal('Another name', 2)

const farm = new Farm(1, 'location', [animal1, animal2])
```

If you don't want to create Animal class. You can just pass array of objects that defines animal.

```js
const farm = new Farm(1, 'location', [
  { name: 'A name', qty: 1 },
  { name: 'Another name', qty: 2 }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Small refactoring to @XMehdi01 answer. Keep constructor arguments followed by an underscore to keep the readability and clarity for future.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(_name, _quantity) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.quantity = _quantity;
  }
}
class Farm {
  constructor(_id, _location, _animals) {
    this.id = _id;
    this.location = _location;
    this.animals = _animals;
  }
}
const animals = [
  new Animal("dog", Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)),
  new Animal("cat", Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)),
  new Animal("shark", Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000))
];
let FarmObject = new Farm(crypto.randomUUID(), "Las Vegas", animals);
console.log(FarmObject);
```

Comment: +1 good you make a difference with the prefix underscore to variables, plus the first time I see `crypto.randomUUID()`, I didn't know its built-in in standard!

Answer (score 0):

For the record: without the [`class sugar`](https://everyday.codes/javascript/please-stop-using-classes-in-javascript/) and as OOP as anything:

```js
const farm = Farm( 1, "MyFarm", 
  [Animal(`Pig`, 3), Animal(`Donkey`, 2), Animal()] );

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `
  <pre>${JSON.stringify(farm, null, 2)}</pre>`);
  
function Animal(name = `unknown`, quantity = 1) {
  return { name, quantity };
}

function Farm(id, location = `unknown`, animals = []) {
  return { id, location, animals };
}
```